# Unzip skipping all files when extracting archive

Tags: zip

I zipped the public folder inside a shared hosting file system, using the command:

```
zip -r file.zip ../public
```

and it created a `file.zip` in the private directory.

I then downloaded the `file.zip` and using FTP copied it into another site using the same file structure and tried to unzip it.

The unzipping won't work, it gives a message `skipping insecure entry` for every file.

What is the cause of this and how do I successfully unzip the files?

Comment: The so-called insecure entries all start with “..”, is that right?

Comment: yes. They all start with "../public/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option in the man page I see that *might* allow this is `-^`.  You should have created the zip with `zip -r private/file.zip public` from the parent directory directory, instead of from the private directory.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is skipping all entries in the archive because extracting them would write to the parent directory.

The `zip` utility stores the file path along with the file content in the archives that it creates, and you archived files in `..`.

Unpacking the archive is considered "unsafe" as it may have unwanted or surprising consequences.

Create the archive again, but this time from the parent directory of the directory that you are archiving.